# Ajax path working for one array, but not another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pull data from an ajax get request. I can access the path to the Fields array, but not the DocImage array. When I run the DocImage path I get

```
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: f.DocImage.map is not a 
function TypeError: f.DocImage.map is not a function
```

Here is my code for the Fields path, which works. For confidentiality reasons I cannot display the URL.

```
 $("#btn").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url:
        "",
      method: "get",
      async: true,
      DataType: "application/json"
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data
        .map(function(f) {
          console.log(f);
          return f.Fields.map(function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            return "<p>" + e.DisplayName + ": " + e.DataValue + "</p>";
          }).join("<br/>");
        })
        .join("<br/>");
    });
  });
```

Here I switch out the Fields for DocImage. And that is were I get the error.

```
 $("#btn").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url:
        "",
      method: "get",
      async: true,
      DataType: "application/json"
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data
        .map(function(f) {
          console.log(f);
          return f.DocImage.map(function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            return "<p>" + e.sfFilename + "</p>";
          }).join("<br/>");
        })
        .join("<br/>");
    });
  });
```

Here is what the the console is displaying for the data.

```
{Fields: Array(8), DocImage: {…}}
DocImage: {sfKey: 4, sfScanIndex: 4, sfFilename: 
"\\"IPAddress"\images\2019-01\16\12896\0000\thisisapdffile.pdf}
Fields: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Try changing `DataType` to `dataType` in the ajax call.

Comment: thats because the doc image is not an array. it is object ...

Comment: when I switch to dataType I get no data at all

Comment: So can I map the object data?

Comment: try changing `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML..` to `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.DocImage.sfFilename;`

Comment: tell me if that works ?

Comment: When I changed it to data.DocImage.sfFilename I get sfFilename is undefined TypeError

Comment: interesting though.. When I changed it to data, DocImage.sfFilename I get DocImage is not defined ReferenceError, but the Doc appends [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: can you show me the output of `console.log(data.DocImage);`

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 
    'map' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of 
    undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:5500/temp.html:44:14)
    at j 
 (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:29999)
    at k (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:30313) undefined

Comment: Made some progress. If I narrow the data to data[0].DocImage I do return the correct data

Comment: @denis then you forgot to mention that data is an array ...

Comment: There's **two** `.map` in the success callback - change the 2nd one, not the first:  `return f.DocImage.sfFilename;`  `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.map(function(f) { return f.DocImage.sfFilename; }).join("<br/>");;`

Comment: @AneesIjaz sorry, you are correct. The initial response is an array with multiple Field and DocImage arrays within them  (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]0: {Fields: Array(8), DocImage: {…}}1: {Fields: Array(8), DocImage: {…}}2: {Fields: Array(8), DocImage: {…}}length: 3

Comment: @freedomn-m I still get cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Exactly where is the error now?  There should be only one `.map` and that's `data.map` which would have been working before as you were getting `f.DocImage.map is not a function`.  Could be time to update the question by *adding* the code that you now have.

Comment: @freedomn-m Tried again with your code and it worked. Can you post it as an answer? Thank you

Comment: @AneesIjaz spotted the issue with his first comment, I just clarified the location - Anees, please add an answer with full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer which you may have already solved from comments.

**Problem**

The DocImage is object and map function does not work for objects.

**Solution**

```
 $("#btn").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url:"",
          method: "get",
          async: true,
          DataType: "application/json"
        })
        .then(function(data) {
         document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data
            .map(function(f) {
              console.log(f);
              return "<p>" + f.DocImage.sfFilename + "</p>";
            })
            .join("<br/>");
        });
    });
```